# ORACLE TRIM and RTRIM: the TRIM (TRAILING… ) select with more than one character?

Tags: oracle, trim, trailing

Why has the lette ’m’ special role in following query? I tried to create a TRIM functions and I am stuck with it. Or: what is the differnce when I query from the dual and another table.

E.g.

I created a table with one column and two values (’adam’ and ’apperda’)

```
create table x
(col1 varchar2(20));
insert into x values ('adam');
insert into x values ('apperda');
```

Then I select the TRIM(TRAILING… ) and the RTRIM as follows:

```
select 
col1,
trim(trailing 'am' from col1) traling,
rtrim(col1, 'am') rtim
from x;
```

And the result: ’ad’ and ’apperd’

```
COL1                 TRALING              RTIM                
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
adam                 ad                   ad                  
apperda              apperd               apperd
```

I don’t understand why `apperd` turns up in the result… It should be an error message, shouldn’t it: ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character?

I tried two other selects:

1. Removed the trim(trailing…) part of the select.

   ```
   select
   col1,
   trim(trailing 'am' from col1) traling
   from x;
   ```
2. Select from dual

   ```
   select
   trim(trailing 'am' from 'apperda'),
   from dual;
   ```

Both query give me the error message:

> ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character

The plus row in a query provides plus information? Or how it is possible? And it is not just the a query question but seems the two data (`adam` and `apperda`) interact:

I create a simple query with `apperda` and it show the error:

```
select 
trim(trailing 'am' from 'apperda') traling,
rtrim('apperda', 'am') rtim
from dual
```

> ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character

---

the core example (2018-07-05)

```
create table trims
(col varchar2(20));

insert into trims values ('dream');

select
    trim(trailing 'am' from col)
    rtrim(col, 'am')
from trims;
```

The first row in the select should give the error ORA-30001, because there are two characters in trim(trailing...). But the script runs:

```
TRIM(TRAILING'AM'FROMCOL)   RTRIM(COL,'AM')
-----------------------------------------------
dre                         dre
```

And: it seems that the trim(trailin...) depends on the rtrim(...) - if you erase the rtrim(...), the error message appears as is should be.

```
select
    trim(trailing 'am' from col)
    --rtrim(col, 'am')
from trims;
```

> ```
> `ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character`
> ```

Comment: Interesting. Looks like quite a weird bug.

Comment: @diaphol - Read the docs - [LTRIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions083.htm  [TRIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) ltrim talks about characters, trim talks about trim_character(single)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal - that doesn't explain why it **doesn't** error sometimes.

Comment: Which version? Your example does give me an error on 12.1.0.2.

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour in 12.2.0.1, but only if the second letter in the 'set' is an 'm' (so far, haven't checked exhaustively), and only if there are multiple rows to check; even with inline view of the two example values from dual unioned (but with only 1 row it does error - kind of seems like it's switching the under-the-hood function for multiple rows, but not sure why the 'm' matters.)

Comment: Trim support single character only. But RTRIM and LTRIM will support string. If you tried TRIM with string then it will throw error like "ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character"

Comment: @kfinity version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: @gaj you are right, but question is why does NOT appear the ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character error

Comment: select 
col1,
trim(trailing 'am' from col1) traling,
rtrim(col1, 'am') rtim
from x;

This will also will throw error? which version of oracle using

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/370b38/1

Comment: @gaj I have run your script in sql*plus (SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0) and SQL Developer (18.1.0) and the error doesn't occur. But the error appears via sql fiddle..

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this is a side-effect of some kernel optimisation. Effectively `trim(trailing 'am' from col)` and `rtrim(col, 'am')` are the same operation. So it seems that if we execute `rtrim(col, 'am')` second Oracle doesn't bother `trim(trailing 'am' from col)` but simply returns the result of the `rtrim()` instead.

Hence while these queries returns the trimmed results ...

```
select
    trim(trailing 'am' from col)
    , rtrim(col, 'am')
from trims;
/

select
    trim(trailing 'ax' from col)
    , rtrim(col, 'ax')
from trims;
/
```

... switching the order of execution hurls `ORA-30001: trim set should have only one character`:

```
select
    rtrim(col, 'am')
    , trim(trailing 'am' from col)
from trims;
/
```

So does providing different values to trim:

```
select
    trim(trailing 'am' from col)
    , rtrim(col, 'ax')
from trims;
/
```

The one snag with this theory is that Oracle executes functions running left-to-right. So it's peculiar that Oracle hurls when the invalid `trim()` is the rightmost function call in the query when we would expect Oracle to object when it's the first function to be executed.